# Complex Analysis-Proof Verification

Tags: proof-verification, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be two holomorphic functions on the disk $D$. If $f(z)g(z)$ $=$ $0$ for all z $\in$ $D$, show that either $f$ or $g$ in constantly zero in $D$.

So this is what I have gotten:

Suppose $f(z)g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in D$

Let $Z(fg) = \{z\in D: \, f(z)g(z)=0\}$ is the zero set of $(fg)$

Then $Z(fg)$ has a limit point in $D$ since $Z(fg) = D$, call the limit point as $\alpha$.

Let $$Z(f) = z\in D \mid f(z)=0$$
$$Z(g) = z\in D \mid g(z)=0$$
Choose $r>0$ such that $B_r$($\alpha$)$\subset$$D$

If $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$ in $B_r$($\alpha$), then $B_r(\alpha)\subset Z(f)$

and since $B_r$($\alpha$) has a limit point in $D$, so does $Z(f)$

hence $f = 0$

Now, if $f\not\equiv0$ in $B_r$($\alpha$), there is some $z_0\in B_r(\alpha)$

such that $f(z_0) \neq 0$

but then $g(z_0) = 0$

Now, let $0<r_1<r$ such that $z_0 \notin Br_1 (\alpha)$

If $f\equiv0$ on $Br_1 (\alpha)$ then, we are done.

If that is not the case, there is $z_1 \in Br_1 (\alpha)$ such that

$f(z_1)\neq 0$. Then, $g(z_1)=0$

Either this process will terminate ($f\equiv 0$ on $Br_c(\alpha)$ for some $i$)

(or) we will have a sequence $(z_c)_{c=0}^\infty$ converging to $\alpha$.

But this sequence is entirely in $Z(g)$

So $Z(g)$ has a limit point in $0$.

Hence by identity theorem, $g\equiv0$ in $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. You did a writing mistake that I corrected: in fact, you wrote $g(z_1) \neq 0$, but it must be $g(z_1)=0$ in order to obtain the correct proof.

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct, but you can simplify it, using essentially the same idea.

Suppose $f(a)\ne0$. By continuity, there exists $r>0$ such that $f(z)\ne0$, for all $z\in B_r(a)$. It is not restrictive to assume $B_r(a)\subseteq D$. By assumption, $g(z)=0$ for every $z\in B_r(a)$. Since this set has a limit point, we conclude $g=0$ on $D$.